# MySQL SELECT command denied to user - MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using a 3rd party hosting services.

They provided me a MySQL DB and a user.

I am running this simple query

```
SELECT * FROM db_a4b20a_reales.properties_residental;
```

I am facing some weird situation, when try to run this query from MySQL Workbench it works, but when I try to run it from my .Net Core 2.2 application I receive the following error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'a4b20a_reales'@'{the server ip...}' for table 'properties_residental'
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.AsyncSelectEnumerable`2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SouthRealEstate.DAL.RealEstateDbServices.GetAllResidentalPropertiesAsync() in C:\omri\work\projects\gitRepo\RealEstateProfessional\SouthRealEstate.DAL\RealEstateDbServices.cs:line 56
```

- I am using the same user both in MySQL Workbench and in my application.
- I am running both from the same host/same env.
- This is my connection str `server=...;port=3306;user id=a4b20a_reales; password=***; database=db_a4b20a_reales; pooling=true; CharSet=utf8; Allow User Variables=True; Convert Zero Datetime=True; default command timeout=720`
- I am using `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore(8.0.16)`
- Please don't answer with `grant permission`, it's not the question.

**UPDATE:**

It's working when using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, seems like the problem is with the `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore(8.0.16)` connector

Comment: You may be connecting to the wrong/a different database (your original query: `db_reales`, the connection string: `db_a4b20a_reales`). Your framework may or may not be using this db depending on how you actually run the code. You could try to use `SELECT DATABASE()` to determine the current database.

Comment: @Solarflare youre confusing the user and database, the query is correct and the connection string is ok, also it is working when i use mysql.data lib

Comment: I meant: `SELECT * FROM db_reales.xxx` -> queries database `db_reales`. `password=***; database=db_a4b20a_reales;` connects to database `db_a4b20a_reales`. Depending on your framework/settings/actual code, this might query a different database.

Comment: @Solarflare wrongly typed in the question, updated. THIS IS NOT THE ISSUE, i am using EF.....

Comment: Please post the full stack for the exception message: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ . Also, have you considered switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql? A lot of people report that it's less buggy than MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: @Bradley Grainger updated + not working with pomelo as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works after replacing to `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` instead of `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore(8.0.16)`.